# How to create Cfn resource with attributes read from CloudFormation parameters that are numeric or boolean?

Tags: aws-cdk

I want to create firehose delivery stream and read buffering hints and `enabled` flag from CloudFormation parameters.

I found how to do it for cases when someone needs a string, eg queue name,

```
new sqs.Queue(this, 'MyQueue', {
   queueName: Fn.conditionIf('Condition', 'Hello', 'World').toString()
});
```

I can't figure out how to do it for number or boolean. What should I use for XXXXXXXXXXXXXX and YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY in the following code?

```
        const cfnParam = new CfnParameter(this, "EnableFirehoseDataFormatConversion", {
            type: "String"
        });

        const cfnCondition = new CfnCondition(this, "FirehoseDataFormatConversionEnabled", {
            expression: Fn.conditionEquals(cfnParam.valueAsString, "true"),
        });

        new kinesisf.CfnDeliveryStream(this, "MyFirehose", {
            // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-extendeds3destinationconfiguration.html
            extendedS3DestinationConfiguration: {
                bucketArn: dataBucket.bucketArn,
                bufferingHints: {
                    intervalInSeconds: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
                    sizeInMBs: 128,
                },
                compressionFormat: "UNCOMPRESSED",
                dataFormatConversionConfiguration: {
                    enabled: YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
                },
                roleArn: myRole.roleArn,
                prefix: dataStoragePrefixInS3,
                errorOutputPrefix: errorStoragePrefixInS3,
            }
        });
```

#### Environment

- **CDK CLI Version:** 1.30
- **OS:** Mac 10.13
- **Language:** Typescript

Answer (score 0):

I found what should I use for YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY.

What's going on? It turns out that types of some values don't have to be a scalar (`string`, `number`, ...) but can be `IResolvable` that allows CDK to evaluate them during synthesis. As an example, here is the declaration of `DataFormatConversionConfigurationProperty` in `node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-kinesisfirehose/lib/kinesisfirehose.generated.d.ts`:

```js
export declare namespace CfnDeliveryStream {
    interface DataFormatConversionConfigurationProperty {
        readonly enabled: boolean | cdk.IResolvable;
        readonly inputFormatConfiguration: CfnDeliveryStream.InputFormatConfigurationProperty | cdk.IResolvable;
        readonly outputFormatConfiguration: CfnDeliveryStream.OutputFormatConfigurationProperty | cdk.IResolvable;
        readonly schemaConfiguration: CfnDeliveryStream.SchemaConfigurationProperty | cdk.IResolvable;
    }
}
```

That means we can use the following for the `enabled` attribute

```js
const cfnParam = new CfnParameter(this, "EnableFirehoseDataFormatConversion", {
    type: "String"
});

const cfnCondition = new CfnCondition(this, "FirehoseDataFormatConversionEnabled", {
    expression: Fn.conditionEquals(cfnParam.valueAsString, "true"),
});

const enabledOrNot: IResolvable = Fn.conditionIf(cfnCondition.logicalId, true, false);

new kinesisf.CfnDeliveryStream(this, "MyFirehose", {
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisfirehose-deliverystream-extendeds3destinationconfiguration.html
    extendedS3DestinationConfiguration: {
        bucketArn: dataBucket.bucketArn,
        bufferingHints: {
            intervalInSeconds: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
            sizeInMBs: 128,
        },
        compressionFormat: "UNCOMPRESSED",
        dataFormatConversionConfiguration: {
            enabled: enabledOrNot
        },
        roleArn: myRole.roleArn,
        prefix: dataStoragePrefixInS3,
        errorOutputPrefix: errorStoragePrefixInS3,
    }
});
```

This approach does not work for XXXXXXXXXXXXXX because type of `intervalInSeconds` is `number` rather than `number | IResolvable`. However, the type of `bufferingHints` is `IResolvable`, so you should be able to specify the whole structure. I don't know yet how to build an instance of `IResolvable` that would return a structure.